# Workbook_BeforeClose if a cell value equal "FAIL"

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a VBA code on my excel forms to notify the user on exit if the outcome result is not PASS. I tried the following code but did not work?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Range("I$64").Value2 <> "PASS" Then
MsgBox "Analysis Outcome is Failed!!!!"
End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestion on this one, please?

Comment: Why are you using `.Value2`?  `.Value` is the usual so try it instead.  Also, it is best to specify which worksheet your range is on.

Comment: Are you sure `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` is being run?  Easily tested by inserting the `Stop` command in the first row of the `Sub`

Answer (score 1):

Qualify the `Worksheet`, and add `Cancel = True` within the `If...End If` to keep the workbook open (if needed).

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Sheet1.Range("I$64").Value2 <> "PASS" Then ' Or maybe Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range...
        MsgBox "Analysis Outcome is Failed!!!!"
        Cancel = True ' as needed
    End If
End Sub
```

This code should be in the *ThisWorkbook* module:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Did not worked. Maybe because the "PASS" is a formula's outcome?

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue. Are you sure you have the right `Worksheet`? Is this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module?

Comment: I used this: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Worksheets("CSG 130")("I$64").Value2 <> "PASS" Then
        MsgBox "Analysis Outcome is Failed!!!!"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: You're missing `.Range` before `("I$64")`

Comment: Still not working and workbook closed without warning:`Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Worksheets("CSG 130").Range("I$64").Value2 <> "PASS" Then
        MsgBox "Analysis Outcome is Failed!!!!"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: Is this in the `ThisWorkbook` module?

Comment: There are all codes I am using: `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSG 130").Copy
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
Path = "Z:\AD000 - Admin\Laboratory Documents\Analysis Result\Archived - Excel\"
filename = Range("B3") & Range("M1")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview ' preview '
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, [B3]) Is Nothing Then
[b64] = Date
End If
End Sub`

Comment: what workbook close event do you want to track? the one you started your macro from or the one you created with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSG 130").Copy`? In this latter case you should have a `Workbook_BeforeClose()` event in it, which is a little tricky...

Comment: Thanks @DisplayName, I tried this: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSG 130").Range("I$64").Value2 <> "PASS" Then
    MsgBox "Analysis Outcome is Failed!!!!"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub` but still closed without warning!?

Comment: Can you confirm that this code is within the `ThisWorkbook` module? Not in a sheet module or code module?

Comment: And can you answer my question, too?